# Calling a function on the result of a promise in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

```
return User.findOne({email: email}).then((user) => {
    return user; });
```

How does the **then** work? When I do `return user`

Does the **WHOLE** `User.findOne({email: email}) ------> user`? Does the first statement transform into a function which returns user, so you are doing:

```
return user;
```

In the end?

When you do **.then**, and return something, what happens to the actual promise (first) statement? (The whole statement before **then**)?

Comment: Are you using a library to query your database? I don't recall that `.findOne` returns a promise.

Comment: @DanielB, Mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of Mongoose, the `.findOne()` used in your code doesn't return a promise but a `query` that has a `.then()` function that yields a value from an async operation. To get a real promise you'd have to use `.exec()` instead, as can be read [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

> Does the WHOLE `User.findOne({email: email}) ------> user`? Does the
>   statement on the left become user, so you are doing: `return user;` in the end?

No. Actually, the whole `.then((user) => { return user; });` part is redundant. The value that the `.findOne(...)` can be accessed by just returning like

`return User.findOne({email: email});` and then accessing the `.then()` of the query later on. To illustrate this, have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vxgeoLb6/) that demonstrates the same thing but with real promises.

> When you do `.then`, and return something, what happens to the actual
>   promise statement? (The whole statement before then)?

Nothing. If you have *real* promises, they are either pending, fulfilled or rejected. The `.then()` function returns a *new* promise that also either is rejected or fulfilled. When you return something from inside a `.then()` function, the returned value is actually resolved, which means that it effectively returns `Promise.resolve(<value>).`

Comment: So when I call .then on the User.findOne then not return User.findOne({email: email}), what does it do? Will it return undefined? If I have a function `function exe () { User.findOne({email: email}).then((result) => {return result;})}`, and I do `exe()`, what is returned?

Comment: That will return `undefined` since you're not doing `{ return User.findOne(..) }`. If you look in my fiddle you'll notice that there is no need to add the `.then()` at all, but instead you should just define the function as `function exe() { return User.findOne({ email: email}); }`

Comment: `function  f () {

   return function g () {
        return "ggggg";
    }

}

console.log(f());` Why does this return `[Function: g]`? and not `ggggg`

Comment: Because you're returning the function declaration. First declare `function g()` outside the `function f()` and then you return the *call* of `g()` like `function f() { return g(); }`

Comment: So when you call `User.findOne({email: email}).then((result) => {return result;})` does it automatically become a function? So now when you return it you return f so like is it the same as `f.then((result) => {return result})`? Where `f` corresponds to the `User.findOne...`

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking - are you asking what happens for Query.then, or are you asking what happens for Promise.then?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the `.then` function is technically deprecated in Mongoose - you're meant to use your own implementation of promises.

That said, looks like mongoose has been using [mpromise](https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise) as it's promise implementation, and the `.then` function is implemented [here](https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise/blob/master/lib/promise.js#L204):

```
Promise.prototype.then = function (onFulfill, onReject) {
  var newPromise = new Promise;

  if ('function' == typeof onFulfill) {
    this.onFulfill(handler(newPromise, onFulfill));
  } else {
    this.onFulfill(newPromise.fulfill.bind(newPromise));
  }

  if ('function' == typeof onReject) {
    this.onReject(handler(newPromise, onReject));
  } else {
    this.onReject(newPromise.reject.bind(newPromise));
  }

  return newPromise;
};
```

---

`.then` just chains a new promise to the execution of the previous promise. In effect you have two promises, which will execute one after the other.